# Clear input history

Tags: jquery, html

*HTML*

```
<form id="send-message">
    <input type="text" id="message"></input>
</form>
```

*JS*

```
 $messageForm.submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());


    $messageBox.val('')
    });
```

[image: img]

I don't want the older insert popup when clicking on the text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `autocomplete` attribute with `off` value :

```
<form id="send-message" autocomplete="off"></form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on some browsers. You have to add it to the form element for the best browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [turn off autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) on your form.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off"
  action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
[...]
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Would do it. This way you can switch the Autocomplete of the Browser off.

Browser saves the Previous **successfull** form submission and would let the user reuse those values when he resubmits the form, or has to resubmit the form. That is a Chrome's Autocomplete popup.

If you use, `autocomplete="off"` for the input, this would be switched off for that particular element.